# Add ActionListener to Netbean GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, events, netbeans

I use NetBeans IDE 8.2 to create my Layout. Unfortunately I cannot find a possibility to add the following code over the NetBeans GUI Builder:

```
JButton b = new JButton("click me");       
b.addActionListener(new MyListener() );
```

I've found only a way, to add the Event "actionPerformed" over the Properties.

Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in your constructor :

```
public ConstructorGUI() {

    super.setUndecorated(true);
    initComponents();
    ...
    JButton b = new JButton("click me");
    b.addActionListener(new MyListener());
    ...
}
```

Or for the better practice you can create a separated method and which you can put this piece of code and call it in your constructor.